# My 5.1 audio system not working properly when I connect to Internet

Tags: drivers, audio, internet

I just bought a Genuis 5005 5.1 audio system, and I have an issue with it: It won't work properly when I get on the Internet (the central speaker isn't working).

I also bought an Asus Xonar DG 5.1 sound card which works perfectly. I installed it and also installed the driver for it.

When I play music/videos from my hard drive, all the speakers work fine, but when I connected to Internet to play videos/music, the center speaker won't work.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very possible that the quality of the streamed audio is not great enough to support the 5.1 setup that you have. Meaning it was only coded to support a 2 channel audio, not 5.